# What is the most elegant way to map one list to another in Java?

Tags: java

I am new in Java so please be patient.

It is common to map (convert) lists to lists. Some languages have a `map` method, some (C#) `Select`. How is this done with Java? Is a `for` loop the only option?

I expect to be able to do something like this:

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
...
List<CustomerDto> dtos = customers.convert(new Converter(){
  public convert(c) {
    return new CustomerDto();
  }
})
```

I have missed something? Please give me a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented something on the fly. See if this helps you. If not, use Google Collections as suggested.

```
public interface Func<E, T> {
    T apply(E e);
}

public class CollectionUtils {

    public static <T, E> List<T> transform(List<E> list, Func<E, T> f) {
        if (null == list)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null list");
        if (null == f)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null f");

        List<T> transformed = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (E e : list) {
            transformed.add(f.apply(e));
        }
        return transformed;
    }
}

List<CustomerDto> transformed = CollectionUtils.transform(l, new Func<Customer, CustomerDto>() {
    @Override
    public CustomerDto apply(Customer e) {
        // return whatever !!!
    }
});
```

Comment: As Steve McLeod's answer, you can be more flexible with your type parameters.

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in way of doing this in Java - you have to write or use a helper class. [Google Collections](http://google-collections.googlecode.com) includes

```
public static <F,T> List<T> transform(List<F> fromList,
                                  Function<? super F,? extends T> function)
```

This works well, but it's a bit clumsy to use, as you have to use a one-method anonymous class and a static method. This is no fault of Google Collections, it is just the nature of doing this type of task in Java.

Note that this lazily transforms items in the source list as needed.

Answer (score 2):

As long as customerDto extends Customer, this will work

```
   List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

   List<CustomerDto> dtos = new ArrayList<CustomerDto>(customers);
```

Otherwise :

```
List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

List<CustomerDto> dtos = new ArrayList<CustomerDto>();

for (Customer cust:customers) {
  dtos.add(new CustomerDto(cust));
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that CustomerDto extends Customer? This is not the case. Thanks for your replay.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't yet a way to apply a mapping function like this to a Java `List` (or other collections). Closures, which will provide this functionality, were seriously considered for the upcoming JDK 7 release, but they have been deferred to a later release due to a lack of consensus.

With current constructs, you can implement something like this:

```
public abstract class Convertor<P, Q>
{

  protected abstract Q convert(P p);

  public static <P, Q> List<Q> convert(List<P> input, Convertor<P, Q> convertor)
  {
    ArrayList<Q> output = new ArrayList<Q>(input.size());
    for (P p : input)
      output.add(convertor.convert(p));
    return output;
  }

}
```

Comment: Minimalist closures are in JDK 1.1.

Comment: I'm not a fan of any closure proposal; inner classes combined with iteration are good enough for me. My point here is that there is no method to apply one to a collection as the poster requested.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find the following shorter and simpler, but if you find the functional approach simpler you could do it that way.  If other Java developers might need to read/maintain the code I suggest using the approach they might feel more comfortable with.

```
List<CustomerDto> dtos = new ArrayList<CustoemrDto>();
for(Customer customer: customers)
   dtos.add(new CustomerDto());
```

You might find this library interesting [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but thought I'd add that I've had good experiences with Apache Commons CollectionUtils' collect method. It's very similar to the Google Collections method above, although I haven't compared them for performance.

http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#collect%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer%29